# ruby math issue with division

Tags: ruby, math, casting, division

I'm calculating Fibonacci numbers with binet's formula and I'm having trouble dividing in ruby.  I've tried casting numbers to_f etc with no avail.  I'll show you what works and what doesn't then maybe you can tell me why.

The following doesn't work

```
n=5
fib=(1 + sqrt(5))**n - (1-sqrt(5))**n / (2**n * sqrt(5))
puts fib #outputs 354.9257634247335 which is a bunch of garbage
```

I've also tried

```
n=5
fib=((1 + sqrt(5))**n).to_f - ((1-sqrt(5))**n).to_f / (2**n * sqrt(5)).to_f
puts fib #outputs the exact same thing as above
```

BUT The following works

```
n=5
fib1=(1 + sqrt(5))**n - (1-sqrt(5))**n
fib2=(2**n * sqrt(5))
fib = fib1/fib2
puts fib.round(0) #outputs 5 which is correct
```

Why do the first 2 examples fail but the latter gives me what I want? This is infuriating!

Comment: On another note, Binet's formula can only practically be used for small values due to the limited precision of floats.

Comment: That's correct,  I would say 5 is a pretty small number :)

Comment: I guess i could use BigDecimal though

Comment: BigDecimal isn't enough. What you really need is to be able to symbolically manipulate radicals, at which point you're better off just using a recursive formula. Binet's formula doesn't actually give you any computational benefits for large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis

```
fib=((1 + sqrt(5))**n - (1-sqrt(5))**n) / (2**n * sqrt(5))
=> 5.000000000000001
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried encapsulating the entire numerator in parenthesis.  Who knows.  Thanks for an answer to a simple question

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with order of operations. Division has higher precedence than subtraction, so in the first two examples, only the second number is being divided.

You need to add a parenthesis around the numerator to make sure both parts are subtraced before being divided.